# Nativescript - uploading images using http module

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm using "nativescript-imagepicker" plugin to get an image from device library.
To do this, i'm calling this two modules:

```
var imagepicker = require("nativescript-imagepicker");
var imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");
```

For now i have some function that shows the gallery, and i can select an image, that next is converted to base64 string and assigned as global variable for later use:

```
model.gallery = function () {
    var img;
    var context = imagepicker.create({mode: "single"});
    context.authorize()
        .then(function () {
            return context.present();
        })
        .then(function (selection) {
            selection.forEach(function (selected) {
                img = selected;
                model.set('avatar', img);
            });
            var source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
            source.fromAsset(img)
                .then(function (imageSource) {
                    var convertedAvatar = imageSource.toBase64String("jpeg",1);
                    global.convertedAvatar = convertedAvatar;
                });
        }).catch(function (e) {
        alert ('Error, please try  again');
    });
};
```

Everything seems to work fine, but please take a look at image quality (1).
I've tried quality of 90, but seems that string was so long that this http call was crashing an app:

```
model.test = function() {
    var base64 = global.convertedAvatar;
    var content = 'type=profile&file='+base64+'&extension=jpeg';
    http.request({
        url: global.host + 'profile/upload',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": global.cType},
        content: content,
    }).then(function (response) {
        global.loaderHide();
        result = response.content.toJSON();
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            success('Success','Data saved.')
        } else {
            global.alerts('Error',result.message);
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        global.alerts('Error', error);
    });
};
```

My question is : i think that my approach is wrong as i have issues. Base64 string is very long. Is there a way to do this right ? 
Am i able to maybe resize image so string can be smaller ?
Or maybe this is API's issue (not accepting very long strings)?
Finally, maybe i need to use another method like background http module for uploading images, not base64 strings ?
Thank you for any ideas.

Below attached image, how long base64 string is even with quality[image] set to 1.

Comment: What you mean by crashing? Did you verify whether your api works as expected, with any REST client like POSTMAN? Also make sure you do not exceed the POST data limit set on your server Or increase it as needed.

Comment: HI @Manoj, thanks. yes its working, when the image is small quality but for larger quality app is going to background without any notice. Im still interested in using base64 but for me the issue is image size, is there a way to make it smaller maybe ? Thank you.